# Managing memory with form creation in C++ Builder / Firemonkey

Tags: c++, forms, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

So far, in my application it has worked out that all additional forms that were created at runtime, should be modal.  Thus, when creating a new form I use something similiar the following block of code:

```
void __fastcall ShowForm( TComponent * Owner )
{
    TForm1 * form = new TForm1( Owner );
    form->ShowModal();

    delete form;
}
```

With this approach, the form's memory is easily deleted after the user has closed it.

However, I am running into an issue when trying to figure out how to handle memory management for a non modal dialog.  Obviously, I can't simply call delete at the end of the `ShowForm` method as the form would be deleted right after it was created.  So I am left with something like this:

```
void __fastcall ShowForm( TComponent * Owner )
{
    TForm1 * form = new TForm1( Owner );
    form->Show();
}
```

Based on [this documentation](http://www.functionx.com/cppbuilder/Lesson07.htm) and a test application I have written, I know that the `form` pointer will be deleted once its owner has been closed.  However, that still leaves me with the following scenario:

Lets say I have `FormA` with a button that creates and shows an instance of `FormB` using code just like the method above.  I now click the button to create a `FormB` and then close `FormB`, three times.  Until `FormA` is closed, the three instances of `FormB` remain in memory.

How do I manage memory for form creation such that the memory allocated for a form is deleted once that form is closed?  Is there a standard best practice for this, or a built in feature I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [TForm::FormClose](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.OnClose) event, and set the `Action` parameter to `caFree`:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
  Action = TCloseAction::caFree;
}
```

The Form will then free itself when it is closed.